# Sequence of random variables is almost surely summable: is the bound uniform?

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Let $\{X_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of nonnegative, real-valued random variables. When someone writes,

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty X_i < \infty$$

almost surely, I interpret it to mean that there exists a $\sigma$-algebra $\Omega'$ with measure equal to $1$ such that, for any $\omega\in\Omega'$,

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty X_i(\omega) = c(\omega) < \infty$$

The question, then, is whether the constant corresponding to each event, $c(\omega)$, is uniformly bounded or not? Can we say $\exists c: c(\omega)<c$ for all $\omega\in\Omega'$?

Comment: No, there need not be any bound for $c(\omega)$.

Comment: And if I say a random variable is bounded almost surely, it doesn't mean the bound is uniform then either?

Comment: $X(\omega) <\infty$ for almost all $\omega$ does not imply that $X$ is a bounded random variable.

Comment: So a bounded random variable and a random variable which is bounded almost surely are distinct. A bounded random variable is a random variable $X$ for which $X(\omega) < c$ for all $\omega$, with $c$ not depending on $\omega$?

Comment: You should say finite  almost surely. One doesn't use the term 'bounded almost surely'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For example, assume $X_1, X_2, X_3,...$ are independent random variables such that $\mathbb{P}(X_n=1)=\frac{1}{2^n}$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_n=0)=1-\frac{1}{2^n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. It easily follows from Borel-Cantelli lemma that the series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty X_i$ converges almost surely. However, the sum can be as large as we want. Moreover, for each $N\in\mathbb{N}$ the event $\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty X_i\geq N\}$ has positive probability. Indeed:

$\mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^\infty X_i\geq N)\geq \mathbb{P}(X_1=1, X_2=1,...,X_N=1)=\prod_{i=1}^N\mathbb{P}(X_i=1)=\prod_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{2^i}>0$